# Hello, I need some help to copy the content of one file to another except from some corrupted lines in tcl

Tags: parsing, copy, tcl

I have a file with some thousands lines with the below format:

1.3.111.2.802.1.1.3.1.6.3.1.2.5.1.2  2  5

Comment: "the last number after the dot" -- is that 463040864 or -858993460? Given the sample input data, what does the output look like?

Comment: Does the last line always start with "CKSUM"?

Comment: you are right, the number after dot which is the 463040864 for this specific line. I'm interesting only for the 1.3.111.2.802.1.1.3.1.7.1.1.7.1.1.463040864 or 
1.3.111.2.802.1.1.3.1.6.3.1.2.5.1.2 
that's why I have split the line in list and again the mentioned part in list.
Yes the last line always starts with CKSUM

Comment: the output file should look like
1.3.111.2.802.1.1.3.1.6.3.1.2.5.1.2  2  5
1.3.111.2.802.1.1.3.1.6.3.1.2.5.1.2  2  1
1.3.111.2.802.1.1.3.1.7.1.1.45.5.1.2     2  5
1.3.111.2.802.1.1.3.1.7.1.1.2.5.1.2  2  1
1.3.111.2.802.1.1.3.1.7.1.1.4.5.1.2 66  3001
1.3.111.2.802.1.1.3.1.7.1.1.7.5.1.2  2  1
1.3.111.2.802.1.1.3.1.7.1.1.8.5.1.2 66  5
1.3.111.2.802.1.1.3.1.7.1.1.45.5.1.2     2  1
1.3.6.1.4.1.2076.74.7.1.0    2  2

Comment: Please add the desired output to the question where it can be properly formatted

Comment: I've add the desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in this case we can try treating each line as a list; the lines seem to be well-formed enough for that (is that first field an OID?)

```
while {[gets $inChannel line] >= 0} {
    if {[llength $line] <= 1 || [tcl::mathop::<= 0 [lindex $line end] 8191]} {
        puts $outChannel $line
    }
}
```

The tricky bit here is the use of `tcl::mathop::<=`, which is the command form of the `<=` expression operator, which allows us to check whether the value (from the last word of the line) is in the range 0 to 8191 without needing to repeat ourselves.

---

A more cautious approach would be this:

```
while {[gets $inChannel line] >= 0} {
    if {[catch {llength $line} length] || $length <= 1} {
        # Ill-formed and short lines get copied
        puts $outChannel $line
        continue
    }

    set value [lindex $line end]
    if {![string is integer -strict $value]} {
        # Lines with non-integers get copied
        puts $outChannel $line
        continue
    }
 
    if {[tcl::mathop::<= 0 $value 8191]} {
        # Lines with values in range get copied
        puts $outChannel $line
    }
}
```

It's possible to not repeat the `puts` but the resulting code is less clear in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. some clarification only. I need to check the first part of each line, let's say i have the first line 1.3.111.2.802.1.1.3.1.6.3.1.2.5.1.2  2  5 
I need to check only the part 1.3.111.2.802.1.1.3.1.6.3.1.2.5.1.2
in this case the last number is 2 so is in the accepted field and this line need to be copied.
but in case of line 
1.3.111.2.802.1.1.3.1.7.1.1.45.1.1.463040864     2  5 since 463040864 is >8191 I will not copy to the temp file. and if there is such entry in the line also the last line with checksum shouldn't be copied.

Comment: I have write this proc 
 proc isstest { inputfile tempfile } {

# open the target file for reading

set in [open $inputfile r]

# open a temp file

set out [open $tempfile w+]

while { [gets $in line] != -1 } {

      set varList_temp [split $line " "]

   set varList_temp1 [lindex $varList_temp 0]

   set varList [split $varList_temp1 "."]

   set ifdx 0

   foreach number $varList {

     set ifdx $number
  }
  
   if { $ifdx >= 1 || $ifdx <= 8191 } { 

        puts $out $line

But I have stacked how to discard the last line checksum if there're corrupted lines

Answer (score 1):

This uses a regular expression to capture the digits following the last dot, instead of `split`s and `lindex`s

```
set in [open $inputfile r]
set out [open $output w]

while {[gets $in line] != -1} {
    if {[string match {CKSUM*} $line]} then continue

    # capture the digits following the last dot
    if {[regexp {.*\.(\d+)} $line -> key]  &&  0 <= $key && $key <= 8919} {
        puts $out $line
    }
}

close $in
close $out
```